# Ionic app build issue

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic2, gradlew

I am new to ionic. I have developed sample application ionic.
When I try to execute below command it gives gradle error.

```
$ ionic build android
```

Below is the build error:

```
Error: /home/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Gradle version is 3.3

Comment: It appears there is a problem with the java compiler. Do you have java installed, both the jre and the jdk?

Comment: run the build command with `--stacktrace` option will get an idea of the issue

Comment: @mnemosdev, Yes I have installed java 1.8

Comment: @suraj, I tried with --stacktrace but it is giving same error.

Comment: no additional info? try with --debug

Comment: with --debug or --info it went till "build dev finished" state. After that it prints JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME paths then it gives the same error. In Debug also it did not give any failure message.

Comment: ionic info: Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.2
Node Version: v7.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346229/ionic-android-build-not-enough-memory-to-start-jvm any chance its a memory issue.

Comment: Do you have android studio installed?

Comment: @mnemosdev, Android studio is installed.

Comment: Did you follow the steps:

- ionic platform add android
- ionic prepare android
- ionic build android

?

Comment: I did not execute - ionic prepare android.

Comment: I tried to execute command in this sequence: ionic platform add android - ionic prepare android - ionic build android. But same error

Comment: where is android studio and sdk located?

Comment: @suraj, I am using Ubuntu 14. Both are located in /usr/local/ folder.

Comment: Thats it..you have a permissions problem. adding answer..try with sudo

Comment: let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK and Android Studio located in **/usr/local/ folder**

You will either have to move it to your home directory (that involves reinstall).

Or run ionic build commands with sudo

```
sudo ionic build android
```

You *could technically* change permissions of the specific sdk and studio folders but  it is **not advisable** especially in /usr directory.

Comment: Moved Android SDK and Android Studio in home directory. It gives same error.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME=/home/Android/android-sdk-linux/

Comment: did you try with sudo?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process is of android studio but may be applicable.