# Android Studio Gradle Wrapper Memory Heap Settings

Tags: performance, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, heap-memory

Using Android Studio 1.3.2 and Gradle Wrapper v2.6

Also have "Use default gradle wrapper" under Build Tools / Gradle settings.

I also modified gradle.properties in [user_dir]/.gradle/ folder as follows:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

But I think the above config is being ignored since I am using gradle wrapper.

How can I set above settings for gradle wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. I created a file `gradle.properties` in the source of my repository.
2. Added `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m`. Any value you are happy here, but better use same value you used in the `dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize` in your `build.gradle`

**Upd.**: below answer didn't work

If it's still an issue, try setting DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xmx512m" in your gradlew or gradlew.bat files. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17701809/722475) are more details