# Could not find or load main class org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmxlg

Tags: cordova, gradle, phonegap

When I give command in cmd window: "phonegap run" from the root directory of the project (App) it gives an error: "Could not find or load main class org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmxlg"/  Even when I run the gradle -v command, the same error is shown. Please guide or help how to install the gradle.  I unpacked the latest version in C drive and environment variable are set. Two variable are set as:
GRADLE.HOME Value= C:\gradle
GRADLE.OPTS value = org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g

Answer (score 0):

setting gradle properties uses slightly different syntax: something like `-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g` (note the capital `-D` prefix) - see syntax [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)

in your case you may want to specify it directly as `-Xmx...` instead because its meant for the JVM running gradle, and not as a property to gradle itself, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808488/how-to-optimize-gradle-build-performance-regarding-build-duration-and-ram-usage)