# set JVM memory limit for Jhipster application started by Gradle bootRun

Tags: java, gradle, jhipster, heap-memory

I have app generated by Jhipster (using gradle).

The problem of setting JVM options -Xmx -Xms is specific when app started from gradle (bootRun).

I was looking for solution in stackoverflow and tried many advices from forums .... but none worked for me. Java application took a lot of memory. 
In the case of more microservices (more JVMs) Java consumes so much memory that it is unusable.

I tried many options like

- modify build.gradle
- set options from command line
- use environment variable

.... but gradle ignored it always.

using gradle ver:
gradlew --version

Gradle 4.9

Build time:   2018-07-16 08:14:03 UTC
Revision:     efcf8c1cf533b03c70f394f270f46a174c738efc

Kotlin DSL:   0.18.4
Kotlin:       1.2.41
Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_172 (Oracle Corporation 25.172-b11)
OS:           Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 amd64

Limiting memory for Jhipster app works fine if starting apps as docker container.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/17701809/3737815 ?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't helped me. One JVM takes 1.5-2.0GB RAM.
I tried all these environment variables in linux:
JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Xmx256m
GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx256m

Comment: I have moved to Maven and it works there. I think it was simpler/faster to move to Maven than look for solutions with Gradle. It was probably problem at specific versions of Gradle, its plugins or some dependencies.
For Maven I used advice form Zhang Buzz:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072187/how-to-configure-heap-size-when-starting-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set heap size parameters by specifying them in Gradle script in `bootRun` as `jvmArgs` list elements.
You may do it in `gradle/profile_dev.gradle` file like this:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xms256m', '-Xmx512m']
}
```

Possibly `bootRun` is already in file in the generated project, so just add `jvmArgs...` in the new line there.

Then it is possible to check on the metrics page if it has been properly set
(http://localhost:8080/admin/metrics)

[image: JVM Metrics from JHipster admin page]